# Ubuntu CPU I/O Rate Spike

Tags: ubuntu, central-processing-unit, io

Getting really crazy spikes today on a Ubuntu server for CPU / IO.

CPU Chart is showing as much as 210% CPU usage - no idea how that is possible. IO has gone as high as 11912. (Usually well under 1000).

Not a server type - I've run top and it shows two root php-cgi processes using 50-60% of CPU each, consistently. Then other processes come and go as expected. I ran vmstat - bo is at 18. I have no idea what that means.

What steps should I take to troubleshoot? What other details should I provide here? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The percent of CPU used is in relation to the usage of a single core.  If a process is using multiple cores the system can report more than 100% CPU utilisation.

You'll need to look into what those php-cgi processes are used for.  When running `top` you can press `c` to show the full command, or you can use `ps -ef | grep php-cgi` to see the full command.  If that doesn't help you can use lsof (e.g. `lsof -P PID`, replacing PID with the process ID) to see what files those processes are accessing.

Check your server logs and application logs (e.g. web server) to see if you are experiencing higher than normal traffic, or if something else is going on.

Comment: +1 This is also why the system load average can go way beyond 1.0 since 1.0 represents 1 single core only.